# Why are my variables undefined outside of my function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to build a website which displays te temperature in the user's area, but my `la` and `lg` variables are undefined outside of my `showPosition()` function, so I can't succesfully call the API to get the weather.

Here's the full code:

```
var la;
var lg;

function getLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation)
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
}

function showPosition(position) {
 la= position.coords.latitude;
 lg= position.coords.longitude;
}

getLocation();

var url="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + la + "&lon=" + lg;
document.getElementById("im").innerHTML="Latitude:" + la;

fetch(url)
 .then((resp) => resp.json())
 .then(function(data) {
   document.getElementById("temper").innerHTML="Temperature:" + data.main.temp;
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   console.log("error: " + error);
 });
```

I decided to test if my `la` and `lg` variables are correct with the `document.getElementById("im").innerHTML="Latitude:" + la` line, but I get `Latitude:undefined`. I did the same test inside the `showPosition()` function and the variables are correctly defined. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `showPosition` doesn't get called immediately (for example it takes some while to initialize the GPS). Therefore you have to wait with your request until you have received your position data:

```
var la;
var lg;

function getLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation)
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
}

function showPosition(position) {
 la = position.coords.latitude;
 lg = position.coords.longitude;

 var url="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + la + "&lon=" + lg;
 document.getElementById("im").innerHTML="Latitude:" + la;

 fetch(url)
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("temper").innerHTML="Temperature:" + data.main.temp;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("error: " + error);
  });
}

getLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation)
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var la= position.coords.latitude;
    var lg= position.coords.longitude;
    fetchTemperature(la, lg); // create a method for fetch temperature and send la and lg to it
}

function fetchTemperature(la, lg){ // method for fetch temperature
    var url="https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + la + "&lon=" + lg;
    document.getElementById("im").innerHTML="Latitude:" + la;

    fetch(url)
     .then((resp) => resp.json())
     .then(function(data) {
         document.getElementById("temper").innerHTML="Temperature:" + data.main.temp;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("error: " + error);
    });
}

getLocation();
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will try that.